# Modify settings after calling RemoteConfiguration.Configure(configFile)?

Tags: .net, remoting, configuration-files, .net-remoting

My application calls `RemotingConfiguration.Configure()` to set up .NET Remoting. But since I need the portName attribute of the channels element to be different each time the application is run, I have to configure this particular setting programatically.

It sounds very simple (and probably is - but I've been searching Google all day for an answer).

So far I have:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(Program.ConfigFilePath, false);

IChannel[] regChans = ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels;
IpcChannel ipcChannel = (IpcChannel)ChannelServices.GetChannel(regChans[0].ChannelName);
```

The debugger shows me that `ipcChannel._serverChannel._prop` would be the hash table to which I need to add an entry such as `["portName"] = uniquePortName`, but I simply cannot see how to access and modify this.

I know I could always scrap the *.config file and do the whole thing programatically, but I *really* don't want to throw away the benefits of having most of the settings easily editable.

Is it too late to modify an `IpcClientChannel` object once `RemotingConfiguration.Configure()` has returned? Obviously I could probably write my own version of `RemotingConfiguration.Configure()`, but that doesn't seem like the Right Way to do things either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've established that what I wanted to do is not possible.

You can *either* use `RemotingConfiguration.Configure()` *or* something like:

```
  IDictionary channelProperties = new Hashtable();
  channelProperties.Add("authorizedGroup", "Everyone");
  channelProperties.Add("portName", "Client-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); // Unique port name
  IpcChannel channel = new IpcChannel(channelProperties, null, null);
  ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);
```

You can't mix and match. At least, that seems to be the case.

(Of course you can still read any of these settings from the *.config file, but the point is you have to explicitly code for all of the options you might want to support.)