# In C# how do I reference the port number configured in app.exe.config?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

In our server, we configure the port in app.config as follows:

```
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="tcp" port="1234" />
         </channels>
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

We then proceed to configure the server with the following C# code:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(string.Format("{0}{1}", appFolder, "app.exe.config"), false);
```

How do I reference the port number after it has been configured short of parsing the file by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is possible after all. After calling RemotingConfiguration.Configure(string, bool), I run the following method:

```
private string GetPortAsString()
          {
             // Parsing
             System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IChannel[] channels = System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels;
             foreach (System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IChannel c in channels)
             {
                System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel tcp = c as System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel;
                if (tcp != null)
                {
                   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelDataStore store = tcp.ChannelData as System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelDataStore;
                   if (store != null)
                   {
                      foreach (string s in store.ChannelUris)
                      {
                         Uri uri = new Uri(s);
                         return uri.Port.ToString(); // There should only be one, and regardless the port should be the same even if there are others in this list.
                      }
                   }
                }
             }

             return string.Empty;
          }
```

This gives me the TcpChannel info I need, which allows me to grab the ChannelUri and get the port.

GRAIT SUCCESS!

Comment: I also imagine it's a similar process for grabbing other connection types, hopefully this info helps others

Answer (score 1):

You can only configure through code or configuration, you can't do both. This means you can't access the configured details via code, (without passing the xml file yourself).

Comment: That's incorrect, I override settings in app.config all of the time via code if necessary, and I know how to pull other configuration settings that are set in the config file. I'm just not super familiar with System.Runtime.Remoting.

Comment: Yep so do I. Remoting config classes are all internal, there's no way to access the configured settings via code that I know of. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215664/modify-settings-after-calling-remoteconfiguration-configureconfigfile).

Comment: Ah, you meant for the Remoting namespace it's all internal. I thought you were generalizing.

Comment: No I meant specifically remoting, have a look in reflector.

Answer (score 1):

I've just taken a look at the `ConfigurationManager` to help get the values you need...unfortunately it doesnt look like there is a sectionGroup for system.runtime.remoting: ie, this call fails:

```
var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var sectionGroup = cfg.GetSectionGroup("system.runtime.remoting");
```

[image]

So it doesn't appear to me you can use anything existing in the framework to extract it nicely. I'm unsure why this sectionGroup doesnt exist in-code.

Comment: It's in RemotingXmlConfigFileData, and even has it's own parser. It's all internal.